# Get DoubleAnimation Reference Object from BeginAnimation

Tags: wpf, animation, code-behind, beginanimations

I want to add a simple double animation with code-behind to apply a fadein to n objects created at runtime:

```
foreach (var rect in howmanyrect) {

   Rectangle bbox = new Rectangle {
       Width = rect.Width, 
       Height = rect.Height, 
       Stroke = Brushes.BlueViolet,
       Opacity = 0D 
   };

   DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation {
        From = 0D,
        To = 1D,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500D),
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1),
        AutoReverse = false
   };

GridContainer.Children.Add(bbox);
Canvas.SetLeft(bbox, rect.Left);
Canvas.SetTop(bbox, rect.Top);

bbox.Tag = da; // <- Look HERE
bbox.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, da);
```

After this, when requested, delete the objects collection with fadeout:

```
foreach (var child in GridContainer.Children) {

    Rectangle bbox = (Rectangle) child;

    DoubleAnimation da = (DoubleAnimation) bbox.Tag; // <- Look HERE
    da.From = 1D;
    da.To = 0D;

    var childCopy = child; // This copy grants the object reference access for removing inside a forech statement
    da.Completed += (obj, arg) => viewerGrid.Children.Remove((UIElement) childCopy);

    bbox.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, da);

}
```

This code works perfectly but it's a workaround. In my first revision I created a new Doubleanimation object in the delete method but when I started the animation every object excetutes the first and the second animation before being deleted.
So I decide to pass a reference to the DoubleAnimation instance with the Tag property and  change the animation properties.

Is there another way to obtain a reference to the DoubleAnimation object attached with BeginAnimation or to avoid the first animation to be repeated?

Thanks
Lox

Comment: It works for me. http://pastebin.com/ArFFC2Uz Also, please see http://sscce.org/ (you should have included code which doesn't work, not your workaround; and should have included complete sample)

Comment: Yes, you're right!
The previous behavior was due to an oversight on my part. I missed to specify the autoreverse property in the doubleanimation object. During my testing I then added the right statement but I had not noticed because I was trying to retrieve the object reference